# What is this plant with leaves that have serrated edges, and white flowers, found in Malaysia?

Tags: plant-identification, malaysia

I am visiting some relatives in Malaysia. They introduced me to this plant and talk about the health benefits of consuming this plant. I am trying to find out more about this plant, but they could only provide the name in the local dialect.

**Update:**
I asked further and confirmed that this plant has a rather roundish white flower. It is currently not blooming so I don't have photos, but the flower is described as small and round, about the size of the first phalanx of the thumb.

The locals call it "Cheng Ma Jin" or some others call it "Tit Ma Cheng". It might be due to different dialects or just pronunciation since they are mostly elderly.

[image: Close up]
[image: Whole plant]
[image: Leaves]

Comment: What's it's name in the local dialect?

Comment: Closest I can get is "Cheng Ma Jin" should be in ke. I am bad with dialects

Comment: Bit of a long shot but you might try asking on our Gardening site.

Comment: Ben, this is on-topic, and interesting, so I don't want you to move it. But if you'd like, @DJClayworth had a good suggestion. I'm active at Gardening:SE and identification questions make up a very large portion of their content. There are experts there from all over the world. You could always check out the site and see what you think. It's only been here a few days, though, so if you're not in a hurry, giving it some time here might be helpful. It's up to you, of course!

Comment: Quick glance makes me think *Ilex* perhaps, but then again (I can't be sure dueto blurry background of picture but) it looks like the leaves are in an opposite arrangement, which rules out any *Ilex* I would know...

Comment: @theforestecologist well, llex is quite a wide range still... maybe if you have a few species that vaguely match the information I have I can look into them and maybe lead me to the one I am looking for.

Comment: @Ben Ilex *was* my lead :p (though, again, probably not a good one). The bigger problem is I'm not familiar at all with other species in that country, so I'm sure there's a bunch of look-a-like stuff there that I don't know about that would throw me off anyway.

Comment: @theforestecologist true... even while I am looking at that plant there were others around that looked similar but somehow the locals could tell the difference...

Comment: It becomes easier when you've seen the same things enough times. I can drive down the local highway at 50 mph and identify individual species out of the blur of green pretty easily, but drop me in Malaysia and I'll be near clueless even at a stand still :p.

Comment: I know this is old, so a long shot - but walnut family springs to mind. Hard to tell from the pictures though, would need photo of flowers for more ID.